# Can't setup configuration on oracle oci8 and xampp php

Tags: php, oracle, xampp, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I can not connect xampp to oracle database. I've gone all the steps, uninstalled xampp install again, but every time I get the error back. I read a lot about it and every time I was returning the same error

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_oci8.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_oci8.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.))

I've do all the steps from this tutorial https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/installing-xampp-for-php-and-oracle-database again error.

```
PHP Version 7.2.11
Architecture    x86
Thread Safety   enabled
Windows 10
Oracle Instant Client Version 12.2.0.1.0    Basic Package - All files required to run OCI, OCCI, and JDBC-OCI (i set PATH also)
DLL List in pecl  = 7.2 Thread Safe (TS) x86
```

I really can't fix this, any help?

Comment: have you looked in the folder to see if `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8.dll` is indeed there?

Comment: Yes, i copy three file from pecl 
1. php_oci8.dll
2. php_oci8_11g.dll
3. php_oci8_12c.dll

Comment: And you get the thread safe version? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I am try all...First 32 version later 64...there is any secret file which I must upload maybe... only @Christopher Jones maybe know what is

Comment: Maybe problem is Laravel any configuration? 
Laravl is 5.6 version